# MS Access SQL, sort by age in a specific order

Tags: sql, ms-access

My task: "Compile an SQL query that outputs a specific store (enter parameter window) the age of the youngest buyer"

I´ve tried some things, but because i´m new to SQL and i have no idea what i´m doing non of them seem to work.

I´d really appreciate, if someone would help me.

Thanks!

Comment: Please add more detail to your question. E.g. table definition or example data from which you need to get the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to know the fields to [`SELECT`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp) (or return) and the table `FROM` which you are querying (asking) data; let's say you have the following tables: `tblStores` (containing a list of stores and related info), `tblCustomers` (containing customers and related info, e.g. ages, names, phone numbers, etc.), and `tblPurchases` (containing all the purchases at all stores by all customers and related info). You want the minimum age of a customer making a purchase at a specfic store, so you could use a [`MIN` aggregating function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_min_max.asp). You would want to join (or relate) the tables based on customers and purchases. See my [`INNER JOIN`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)s in the example below. Then you filter the result by the user-inputted store name (inputStoreName) using [`WHERE`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp); since the inputStoreName is undefined, in Access this would cause the parameter entry popup window to appear.

```
SELECT list of fields or aggregating functions you want (comma-separated)
FROM list of tables the fields are in (comma-separated) and how to join the tables
WHERE list of conditions to filter the data (separated by AND or OR)
```

Example:

```
SELECT tblStores.Name, tblStores.Description, MIN(tblCustomers.age)
FROM tblStores INNER JOIN ( tblPurchases INNER JOIN tblCustomers on tblPurchases.customerID = tblCustomer.customerID) ON tblStores.storeID = tblPurchases.storeID
WHERE (tblStores.Name = inputStoreName);
```

I recommend checking W3 schools. They are usually helpful for most programming tasks. If you provide more info about your database, we can provide more directed help.